# Macro in Excel Stops in one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA and I am having a small problem. This is my code:

```vb
Sub my_first_macro()
    Range("D4") = "My text Here"
    Range("I4") = "1"
    Range("D5").Select
End Sub
```

The idea of this macro is to have a button associated to it

- that would fill the cell D4 with "My text Here" AND I4 with "1".
- When I hit for the second time it would fill the cell D5 with "My text Here" AND J4 with "1".
- And then, when I hit for the third time it would fill the cell D6 with "My text Here" AND K4 with "1".
- And then, when I hit for the fourth time it would fill the cell D7 with "My text Here" AND L4 with "1".

It's really simple but I am not able to solve this.

Any help?

Comment: `always going to the next row` - what would be *the* next row?

Comment: But then you run it again manually, at some point later? Do you move the selection in the meantime? Do you mean that it should act on the current active row, whatever that may be at the moment when you click the button? Or on the row that is after the one that was last affected by this very macro?

Comment: Then think about how you must persist which row you affected last. A static variable is a solution, but it's not reliable in Excel because the project may get reset. A hidden sheet where you store this is more reliable.

Comment: At once, without pausing and running each row separately?

Comment: @GSerg I edited the quetion. I think it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

To make the value of the currently selected cell "1" and select the cell underneath it you can do:

```
Sub my_macro()
    Selection.Value = "1"
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. I think its almost this.  How should I icnlude the text  : "My text here"

Comment: @Laura `I think its almost this` - given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70525025/macro-in-excel-stops-in-one-cell?noredirect=1#comment124666935_70525025, it very much isn't.

Comment: @ljdyer I edited the quesion. Ithink it is more clear now. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

### Shifting Row and Column at the Same Time

- Modify the `cCell` and `rCell` ranges to see its flexibility.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub my_first_macro()
    
    Dim cCell As Range: Set cCell = Range("D4")
    Dim rCell As Range: Set rCell = Range("I4")
    
    Dim cfRow As Long: cfRow = cCell.Row
    Dim cCol As Long: cCol = cCell.Column
    
    Dim rRow As Long: rRow = rCell.Row
    Dim rfCol As Long: rfCol = rCell.Column
    
    Dim cLastRow As Long: cLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print cLastRow, cfRow
    
    If cLastRow < cfRow Then
        cCell.Value = "My text Here"
        rCell.Value = "1"
    Else
        Cells(cLastRow + 1, cCol).Value = cCell.Value
        Cells(rRow, cLastRow + rfCol - cfRow + 1).Value = rCell.Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but its *only* update I4. When I run the sub for the second time J4 should *also* be "1"

Comment: When I run this code, the first time cells `D4` and `D5` are `My text Here` and cells `I4` and `J4` are `1`. The next time, additionally, cell `D6` is `My text Here` and cell `K4` is `1`...etc. If this is not what you need, please share what is wrong with it. BTW, do you have data in column `D` below cell `D4`?

Comment: I edited the question. Its more clear now. Sorry for the english;.

Comment: Also when I run this code, `J4`, `K4`and `L4`  are not `1`. Only `I4` is `1`

Comment: Sorry, I've modified my answer again. It's trickier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: I've commented my code.

```
Public Sub shift_text_and_numbers()

'Use lngCounter as static variable, that means it keeps its value under the following conditions
'1. if the sub is finished and called again and
'2. as long as there occurs no error in your vba-project and
'3. your workbook is open
    
    Static lngCounter As Long

'Provide your content here

    Dim strText As String: strText = "My text here"
    Dim lngNumber As Long: lngNumber = 1

'Set the first cell for each shift

    Dim rngStartCellText As Range: Set rngStartCellText = Worksheet1.Range("D4")
    Dim rngStartCellNumber As Range: Set rngStartCellNumber = Worksheet1.Range("I4")
    
'Check, whether the required rows and columns are full of data
    
    If _
        rngStartCellText.Row + lngCounter > Worksheet1.Rows.Count Or _
        rngStartCellNumber.Column + lngCounter > Worksheet1.Columns.Count _
    Then

'If the rows and columns are full of data, leave this routine

        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
'Calculates the next cell depending on lngCounter and the first cells, represents also your sheme

    Dim rngNextCellText As Range: Set rngNextCellText = Worksheet1.Cells(rngStartCellText.Row + lngCounter, rngStartCellText.Column)
    Dim rngNextCellNumber As Range: Set rngNextCellNumber = Worksheet1.Cells(rngStartCellNumber.Row, rngStartCellNumber.Column + lngCounter)

'Check, whether there is already the required data in the next cell

    If _
        rngNextCellText.Value = strText Or _
        rngNextCellNumber.Value = lngNumber _
    Then

'Count up for the next call

        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
 
'If there is already the data, repeat the routine

        shift_text_and_numbers

'Check, whether the next cells are already filled with data
'Avoids overwriting of data

    ElseIf _
        VBA.Len(rngNextCellText.Value) > 0 Or _
        VBA.Len(rngNextCellNumber.Value) > 0 _
    Then
    
'If the next cells contain data, leave the routine

        Exit Sub
    
    Else

'Write the content in the next cells

        rngNextCellText.Value = strText
        rngNextCellNumber.Value = lngNumber

'Count up for the next call

        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Thanks @VBasic2008 for learning a new way to declare variables lovely.